# Cannot use loaded Oracle.ManagedDataAccess assembly in Powershell

Tags: oracle, powershell, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am trying to connect to an existing oracle database using Powershell and Oracle.ManagedDatabaseAccess.dll. I have the code running in C# using the very same library.
The assembly is loaded but i cannot use it.

I am using Win10 and Powershell ISE.
I also use VS2017/15.3.2 and .Net 4.7.02046.

I tried using "Add-Type -AssemblyName" and "Add-Type -Path" which did not work at all. Both options showed errors immediately.

I was able to call

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("myrootpath\.nuget\packages\oracle.manageddataaccess.core\2.18.5\lib\netstandard2.0\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll")
```

but i got:

```
GAC    Version        Location 
---    -------        --------                                                                                                                                                                
False   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess\v4.0_2.0.18.3__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
```

I added the Assembly manually to the GAC using gcautil.
Now i get

```
GAC    Version        Location   
---    -------        --------                                                                                                                                                                
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess\v4.0_2.0.18.3__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
```

Now when i call:

```
$command = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sql,$conn)
```

i get the following error:

```
New-Object : The Type [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection] cannot be found. Make sure that you load the Assembly that contains this Type.
In Line:2 Character:8
+ $conn= New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($c ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I read about the solution to compile a small C# console application (since that works) and call it from powershell. This might be feasible, however i really want to understand what the issue is here.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

## Update/Edit:

```
PS H:\> Add-Type -Path "C:\mypath\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
Add-Type : At least one type in the assembly could not be loaded.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], ReflectionTypeLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
 
PS H:\> $error[0].Exception.LoaderExceptions[0]
The type "System.IO.Stream" in the assembly "netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" could not be loaded.
```

Netstandard2.0.0.0 is a requirement for the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll, which also had to be installed in my VS project.

System.IO.Stream should be available in PS without loading. Might be a version conflict because my main development environment is .Net 4.7.02046?

Comment: What was the error message with the `-Path` parameter?  That's how you're supposed to load dlls.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what failure PS reported when you attempted `Add-Type`.

Comment: Thank you. I just edited the post with that information.

Comment: Does anyone have any more suggestions? I am still stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 4):

**First** of all, you need to make sure the version of the NuGet Assembly you're using is compatible with the version of PowerShell you're using.  You mentioned that you're writing code on Windows 10 in the PowerShell ISE.  Since PowerShell ISE does not support PowerShell Core and Windows 10 Anniversary includes 5.1 [out of the box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/set-up-your-computer-for-windows-powershell/download-and-install-windows-powershell-5-1), I'm going to assume you're writing code in Windows PowerShell, not the newer [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/powershell/powershell).

This is important, because up to Windows PowerShell 5.1, PowerShell was based on the .NET Framework, while with PowerShell Core Microsoft switched to the multi-platform .NET Core.  And as it happens, *Oracle publishes different versions of the Oracle Data Provider for each*.

When using the .NET Framework (Windows PowerShell 5.1 and below), use [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess)

When using .NET Core (PowerShell Core 6 and above), use [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/)

**Second**, you need to import the assembly into the current session.  While this sounds easy enough, Oracle had the brilliant idea of using the same assembly name for both Core & non-Core versions, managed & unmanaged, so you're going to want to do that with the full assembly path.  Otherwise it's likely you'll unreliably import an incompatible version.

Fortuitously you can combine both finding the assembly and downloading it if missing into a quick operation using only native PowerShell Commands run in the userspace.

1. Use `Get-Package` to check if ODP.NET is installed already and get it's location.
2. If a `ObjectNotFound` exception is returned, download ODP.NET from NuGet.org using `Install-Package`.
3. If a `ObjectNotFound` exception is returned, install NuGet.org as an untrusted PackageProvider.
4. Import the newly installed assembly explicitly via `Add-Type` and the assembly path.

You can then use ODP.NET in PowerShell as expected.

## Example Implementation

```
#Requires -PSEdition Desktop

try { $nugetPkg = (Get-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess -ProviderName NuGet -MinimumVersion "19.3.1" -ErrorAction Stop -Debug:$false).Source }
catch [System.Exception] {
    if($_.CategoryInfo.Category -eq "ObjectNotFound") {
        # Register NuGet.org as a package source if it is missing.
        try { Get-PackageSource -Name "nuget.org" -ProviderName NuGet -Debug:$false -ErrorAction Stop }
        catch [System.Exception] {
            if($_.CategoryInfo.Category -eq "ObjectNotFound") {
                Register-PackageSource -Name "nuget.org" -Location "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" -ProviderName NuGet -Debug:$false
            }
            else { throw $_ }
        }

        # Install Oracle drivers.
        $pkg = (Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess -ProviderName NuGet -MinimumVersion "19.3.1" -Verbose -Scope CurrentUser -Force -Debug:$false).Payload.Directories[0]
        $nugetPkg = Join-Path -Path $pkg.Location -ChildPath $pkg.Name
        Remove-Variable pkg
    }
    else { throw $_ }
}
# Add ODP.NET to the assemblies available in-session.  Using the path instead of AssemblyName avoids conflicts with ODP.NET (Core).
# See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/18.3/odpnt/index.html for documentation.
Add-Type -Path (Get-ChildItem (Split-Path ($nugetPkg) -Parent) -Filter "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" -Recurse -File)[0].FullName


# Begin Query Operations
try {
    # TESTB connection string.  You can replace the Data Source value with a tnsnames alias.
    $con = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(
        "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=testb)(PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=testb))); User Id=test;Password=user;"
        )
    $con.Open()
    Write-Host ("Connected to database: {0} – running on host: {1} – Servicename: {2} – Serverversion: {3}" -f $con.DatabaseName, $con.HostName, $con.ServiceName, $con.ServerVersion) -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Black

    # Get a single value
    Write-Host "Returning a Scalar Value from Oracle" -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Black
    $cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
    $cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 'Hello World!' FROM DUAL"
    $cmd.ExecuteScalar()

    # Get several defined values
    Write-Host "Retrieving manually typed ordinals from v`$version via OracleDataReader" -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Black
    $cmd.CommandText = 'SELECT BANNER FROM v$version'
    $rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
    while ($rdr.Read()) {
        $rdr.GetString(0)
    }
    $rdr.Dispose()

    # Use a DataAdapter to get defined Data objects.
    Write-Host "Using a DataAdapter to return NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS from Oracle" -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Black
    $adap = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS",$con)
    # Create the builder for the adapter to automatically generate the Command when needed.
    $oraCmdBldr = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommandBuilder($adap)
    
    [System.Data.DataSet]$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $adap.Fill($dataset,"NLSSesParams")
    $dataset.Tables["NLSSesParams"]
    Remove-Variable dataset
}
catch {
    Write-Error ("Can't open connection: {0}n{1}" -f $con.ConnectionString, $_.Exception.ToString())
}
finally {
    if ($con.State -eq 'Open') { $con.close() }
    $con.Dispose()
    Write-Host "Disconnected from database" -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Black
}
```

### Example Output

```
Connected to database: testb – running on host: bat – Servicename: testb – Serverversion: 11.2.0.4.0
Returning a Scalar Value from Oracle
    Hello World!
Retrieving manually typed ordinals from v$version via OracleDataReader
    Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
    PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
    CORE    11.2.0.4.0  Production
    TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
    NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Using a DataAdapter to return NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS from Oracle
    17

Disconnected from database
    PARAMETER               VALUE                       
    ---------               -----                       
    NLS_LANGUAGE            AMERICAN                    
    NLS_TERRITORY           AMERICA                     
    NLS_CURRENCY            $                           
    NLS_ISO_CURRENCY        AMERICA                     
    NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,                          
    NLS_CALENDAR            GREGORIAN                   
    NLS_DATE_FORMAT         DD-MON-RR                   
    NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE       AMERICAN                    
    NLS_SORT                BINARY                      
    NLS_TIME_FORMAT         HH.MI.SSXFF AM              
    NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM    
    NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT      HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR          
    NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
    NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY       $                           
    NLS_COMP                BINARY                      
    NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE                        
    NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP     FALSE
```

This code can be easily modified to work in PowerShell Core by:

1. Replacing `#Requires -PSEdition Desktop` with `#Requires -PSEdition Core`
2. Changing the Installation assembly from `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` to `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core`
3. Changing the `-MinimumVersion` parameter value of `Get-Package` and `Install-Package` from `"19.3.1"` to `"2.18.3"`.

Answer (score 0):

I copy file 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll' to folder with ps1 script
(not installed Oracle Client) and use code:

```
# powershell script in Windows 10  
using assembly ".\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"

using namespace Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

$constr = "User Id=user;Password=pass;Data Source=server:1521/sid";
try {
   $con = new-object OracleConnection($constr);
   $con.Open();
} catch {
  write-host "ERROR: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
  exit;
}
$cmdQuery = "SELECT 'Hellow!' FROM dual"
$cmd = new-object OracleCommand($cmdQuery);
$cmd.Connection = $con;
$cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text;
try {
    $reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader();
} catch {
     write-host "ERROR: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
     $con.Close();
     $cmd.Dispose();
     $con.Dispose();
     exit;
}

while ($reader.Read()) {
        write-host $reader.GetString(0)
    } ;
$con.Close();
$cmd.Dispose();
$con.Dispose();
```